Secure Boot after Dual booting
I have windows 11, and dual booted it with Ubuntu 22.04 (initially, 20.04 and later upgraded). Now, in windows 11, some app requires secure boot to be ON. Is it safe to enable secure boot, even though initially I had it off during dual booting?

Try it and find out. I have not heard secure boot destroying Ubuntu. Once you turn secure boot on, Ubuntu may not boot. I am no sure. You have to try it.

If you installed with UEFI Secure boot on, it installs the Secure boot versions of grub, kernel & drivers. If you have nVidia bit more complicated as you have to create your own MOK, machine owner key to have that driver work for secure boot. You can use live installer to reinstall, kernel & grub boot loader if required. Full reinstall not required.

@user68186 I fear, that if I try it once and it doesn't boot, then it wont boot even after I disable secure boot. Do you know if something like that can happen? Or will it boot after I disable?

What app, and why? I have never heard of any ordinary program needing SecureBoot and I disable it on all of my computers.
